# Eevee transparent glass on transparent background?

Tags: materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine, lighting

In Blender 2.8's Eevee renderer, I have "Transparent" checked in the film tab, and my material settings follow all listed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN9lkS7K04k).

Yet my glass is always this white gray:

[image: screenshot from an Eevee render showing the relatively dark and diffuse glass]

My volumetrics are off. I don't see a transparent glass checkbox. What is the problem here?

Comment: I really hope someone finds an answer to this, I thought eevee was the answer to all problems of render times. I think eevee just needs to adopt _some_ of the things the blender internal renderer did, (allowing more control over shadows and such)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have to cheat it with a specific shader set to alpha Blend, and enabling screen space reflections:

[image: setup]

Answer (score 0):

The *Transparent Glass* option only exists in Cycles. Eevee doesn't have this feature.

Comment: are you sure? I'm sure eevee can render transparency somehow.

Comment: So there's no way around this?

Comment: yet... maybe 2.81 with new transparency in Eevee (could someone test it?)

Comment: @HenrikD Is there supposed to be different handling of transparency in 2.81? I haven't read/found anything about it and the options are the same in the UI.

Comment: @rjg https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Eevee

Comment: @HenrikD Doesn't apply to Glass BSDF and Translucent BSDF out of the box, you would have to use it in combination with the Holdout. I'll see if I can come up with a node setup for this.

Comment: @HenrikD A *Mix* shader between a *Glass BSDF* and *Holdout* and *Fresnel* as factor for the mix doesn't really look good.