# How to do transparent glass on transparent background in eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, glass

im trying to create a glass window, that will partially show the transparent background. However, the glass doesnt show the background, but rather the blender internal sky sphere used for my lighting and rflections in the viewport. How can i make the glass not show the sky but the transparent background instead? I attached an image for reference.

Thanks in regards.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the only way to do this is with the transparent shader rather than the glass shader: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150686/eevee-transparent-glass-on-transparent-background